# How does an Erlang process bind to a specific scheduler?

Tags: erlang

How does an Erlang process bind to a specific scheduler?

Comment: Could you please expand a bit more? I'm not sure about what you're asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605183/how-if-at-all-do-erlang-processes-map-to-kernel-threads/605631#605631 - this answer might actually answer your question. As of binding processes to specific schedulers, AFAIK it is impossible in Erlang VM ATM.

Answer (score 2):

Currently processes does not get bound to specific schedulers (though you can force it via undocumentet functions, not recommended). Scheduler threads may be bound to logical processors using cpu topology and binding types. The vm does use some of this information to enhance performance in its normal scheduling scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from [an old mail from Kenneth Lundin](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/Some-facts-about-Erlang-and-SMP-td2108770.html):

> The Erlang VM without SMP support has 1 scheduler which runs in the 
>   main process thread. The scheduler  picks runnable Erlang processes
>   and IO-jobs from the run-queue and  there is no need to lock data
>   structures since  there is only one thread accessing them.
>
> The Erlang VM with SMP support can have 1 to many schedulers which are
>   run in 1 thread each. The schedulers pick runnable Erlang processes 
>   and IO-jobs from one common run-queue. In the SMP VM all shared data 
>   structures are  protected with locks, the run-queue is one example of
>   a data structure  protected with locks.
>
> > From OTP R12B the SMP version of the VM is automatically started as 
> >     default if the OS reports more than 1 CPU (or Core) and with the same 
> >     number of schedulers as CPU's or Cores.

Not sure if this answer your question. Could you expand a bit more?

Comment: Every scheduler has itself special run-queue independent other scheduler in R13B.