# erlang threading and OS threads correlation

Tags: multithreading, erlang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How, if at all, do Erlang Processes map to Kernel Threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605183/how-if-at-all-do-erlang-processes-map-to-kernel-threads)

I know that erlang is green threaded (not OS threads, more lightweight) but I wanted to know what it does with OS threads.. does it have only one, or maybe 1 per cpu?

Comment: This was kind of answered before, you might want to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767145/erlang-virtual-machine-map-to-which-kernel-thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775714/how-does-an-erlang-process-bind-to-a-specific-scheduler, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605183/how-if-at-all-do-erlang-processes-map-to-kernel-threads/605631#605631